# Can not execute BargainFinderMaxRQ. "Bad EA owner code" error

Tags: sabre

Cannot execute BargainFinderMaxRQ query.
I try to execute simple flight search, but
i receive error: DSF server returned an error: Bad EA owner code

My query:

```xml
...
        <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Target="Production" Version="5.2.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="5.2.0">
            <POS>
                <Source PseudoCityCode="PCC">
                    <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
                        <CompanyName Code="TN"/>
                    </RequestorID>
                </Source>
            </POS>
            <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
                <DepartureDateTime>2019-11-10T11:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="MOW"/>
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LED"/>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true">
                <CabinPref PreferLevel="Preferred" Cabin="Y"/>

            </TravelPreferences>
            <TravelerInfoSummary>
                <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
                <AirTravelerAvail>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                </AirTravelerAvail>
            </TravelerInfoSummary>
            <TPA_Extensions>
                <IntelliSellTransaction>
                    <RequestType Name="50ITINS"/>
                </IntelliSellTransaction>
            </TPA_Extensions>
        </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Errors in the response

```xml
 <Errors>
            <Error Type="SCHEDULES" Code="PROCESS" ShortText="DSF server returned an error: Bad EA owner code 'EXT'"/>
            <Error Type="IF2" Code="PROCESS" ShortText="No complete journey can be built in IF2/ADVJR1."/>
            <Error Type="WORKERTHREAD" Code="TRANSACTIONID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="4259351061194214838"/>
            <Error Type="SERVER" Code="ASECT2LAPC00015.IDM.SGDCPROD.SABRE.COM" MessageClass="I" ShortText="27040"/>
            <Error Type="DRE" Code="RULEID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="21728"/>
            <Error Type="DEFAULT" Code="RULEID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="25238"/>
            <Error Type="SCHEDULES" Code="MSG" MessageClass="I" ShortText="NO FLIGHT SCHEDULES FOR QUALIFIERS USED"/>
            <Error Type="ERR" Code="ERR" ShortText="Error during Processing"/>
         </Errors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation for the Bargain Finder Max API:-
https://developer.sabre.com/sites/default/files/2020-04/BargainFinderMax_NDC_Guide_2020.pdf

The documentation provided has examples for the same.

In all probability, either your PCC is not enabled to consume BFM or the tier level (50, 100, 200) you specified does not match your BFM agreement.

The solution is as under: -

1. Ensure your PCC is enabled to consume BFM. Contact your Sabre account manager to validate if your PCC has been configured to consume BFM.
2. Adjust the BFM tier level to the appropriate one according to your BFM agreement.
3. Review the qualifiers used on your request to ensure those are not overly-restrictive – Example, requesting non-stop flights in a route where non-stop flights do not operate.